# How to use helpers for list objects

Tags: python-2.7, web2py-modules

I have this code:

```
my_table = db.define_table('my_table',
    Field('mt_table_id', 'id', requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY()]),
```

I need to add something like `requires= IS_LIST()` to get a list e.g. `['a','b','c']` instead of `['a,b,c']`. How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ain't got what you meant, but perhaps you should look at custom validators section in web2py's book: http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-validators

You may create a custom validator called IS_LIST() and change the "formatter" method to return a list in the way that you want.